# QGIS, how do you break segments of a polygon, ie break 1 polygon into 2 or more?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a polygon but would like it to be in broken up to put into different layers. I can't work out how to do this.

Comment: do you have one polygon or one layer with multiple polygons? which rules do you want to apply? we need more info

Comment: 1 layer with multiple polygons. I want to split one of them up into smaller multiple polygons.

Comment: Do you want to split up them based on an attribute?  Do you wish to cut them against another polygon or polyline layer? What do the polygons represent?  More information please.

Comment: They have the same attribute and that is fine. I wish to keep them in the same layer. There are two polygons that are snapped to the same line and therefore share many nodes. I want to be able to move or delete the nodes of one polygon without interfering with the other one. At the moment I can move/delete a node which then affects both polygons.

Comment: @Liz: to be able to move or delete the nodes of one polygon without interfering with the other one, you can go to Settings -> Snapping options -> uncheck the box with label "Enable topological editting". Then you can edit vertices of each polygon separately.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, you could either use the 'split features' tool (line with black scissors) to cut a single polygon into several pieces or, if you want to create several layers/shapes from one shape, select the features you want to separate and save the selection as new shapfile. (right click on the layer -> save selevtion as)

Comment: I want to cut a single polygon into pieces and tried the the s'split features' tool. It came up with an error

Comment: "The geometry is invalid. Please repair before trying to split it." and it has created more nodes! I think I am using it wrong.

Comment: I want the polygons to be unconnected and completely separate.

Comment: Try 'Vector -> Geometry tool -> Check geometry validity' to fix the polygon.

Comment: how do i fix the polygon after i Check geometry validity?